# How To Remove Black Line Below AppBar Header When We Scroll Page in Flutter APP (iOS & Android)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, appbar, flutter-appbar

**How To Remove Black Line Below AppBar Header When We Scroll Page in Flutter APP?**

Answer (score 0):

> Used below simple solution below to remove the black line when we scroll the page;

```
AppBar(
  elevation: 0.0,
  scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
);
```

> This code should be located inside your "MyApp" class (main.dart
> file)

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      scrolledUnderElevation: 0, // This removes the black line below app bar header
    )
  ),
);
```